# Join Two tables in dse using solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    parent_id int,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_actions(
    parent_id int,
    user_id text,
    type text,
    created_at int,
    data map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY(parent_id, created_at )
);
```

I am new to solr and cassandra and I want to join these two tables on parent ID using solr

Currently I am joining using spark but i need a solr query to join. I have looked for other option but not able to get the idea to run query in cqlsh, Or to do it in spark code

I wanted to do something like this:

```
select * from users join user_actions on parent_id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using DSE Search, you can join search indexes, similar to what you're trying to do. There are restrictions to their use, however. For example, the two tables must have the same partition key and reside in the same keyspace. This is to ensure you don't perform cross-node joins.

You may want to check out the following video:
https://academy.datastax.com/units/joins?resource=ds310

Assuming you've met the restrictions, I think you're query could go something like:

```
select * 
from <keyspace>.users
where solr_query = '{!join fromIndex=<keyspace>.user_actions}parent_id:*"';
```

That assumes no filter on the parent_id value itself. You could have other filters - I just used parent_id as I don't know any of the other columns in your tables.

Hopefully this helps?

-Jim

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can I add more column if that is the part of partition key. can I add create date as well along with customerId. And Can I select column of both tables.

Comment: You can only select out of the one table, but you can pull as many columns out of that one table as you'd like.