# Is it possible to do a JOIN on two tables based on a search string?

Tags: join, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have two cassandra tables, say student_record and student_personal. Both have one common column "s_id". I want to achieve something like MSSQL join here using Solr by merging rows from both the tables where some specific condition is satisfied or a simple search.

I tried something like this but didn't work

http://localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.solr_table1/select/?q{!join+fromIndex=keyspace.solr_table2}key:value

is this possible or not in Solr?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join Two tables in dse using solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806644/join-two-tables-in-dse-using-solr)

Answer (score 0):

You can "join" two tables provided both are indexed by DSE Search.

DataStax Enterprise supports Apache Solr's cross-core JOINs, i.e. join search documents between two different Solr cores based on a field that is the same partition key between the two CQL tables.

In your case, it may not have worked if the JOIN does not satisfy all the prerequisites. For a complete list, see [Joining cores in DataStax Enterprise](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/joiningSolrCores.html). Cheers!